# Python: How to generate a sequence skipping n numbers each m numbers

Tags: python, range, sequence

I am currently learning Python and I have seen that using `list(range(start,stop,step))` we can create a sequence of numbers going from `start` to `stop-1` with a certain `step` between consecutive numbers.

But I don't know if there is way of achieving a sequence of numbers but skipping `n` of them each `m` numbers.

As an example, if we had the next list of numbers:

```
list(range(0,20))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

If we wanted to skip `n=2` numbers each `m=3` numbers, then the result would be:

```
[0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12, 15, 16, 17]
```

Or if we wanted to skip `n=3` numbers each `m=5` numbers, then the result would be:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

I there a way to do it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes of course it’s possible: you just write the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a one liner that skips n every m numbers:

```
result = [j for i in range(0,20, n+m) for j in range(i, m+i)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, great answer :). There is just a minor sidenote because numbers being >= ```20``` may get added too for some combinations of ```m``` and ```n``` (e.g. ```n=3``` and ```m=6```). This is solved just by adding a condition at the end ```[j for i in range(0,20, n+m) for j in range(i, m+i) if j<20]```

Comment: @JavierTG I like it!  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
nums = range(0,20)
n = 2
m = 3

new_nums = []
while len(nums) != 0:
  if len(nums) < m:
    new_nums.extend(nums[:len(nums)])
    nums = []
  new_nums.extend(nums[:m])
  nums = nums[m:]
  nums = nums[n:]


print(new_nums)
```

Here's a verbose way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

My small constribution

```
m=3
n=2
a=list(range(0,20))
frames=[(a[i*(m+n):i*(m+n)+(m+n):][:n]) for i in a]
frame2=[]
b=[frame2.extend(i) for i in frames]
print(frame2)

[0, 1, 5, 6, 10, 11, 15, 16]
```

Comment: Works also perfect. But it just needs to interchange ```m``` for ```n```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about a one-liner as simple as `range()`, but this should work:

```
n=3
m=5

numbers = []
for i in range(0, 20, n+m):
    for j in range(i, m+i):
        numbers.append(j)
```

Calling numbers output: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]`

Comment: This simply won't work. Please double check the results!

Comment: I have just edited it so that it works. It was only a small error. The n+i needed to be m+i.

Comment: Thanks for the help :) (+1). I hadn't checked it before, but it works also like pakpe's answer.